# Is there a way to play sound on mobile when task finished

Tags: r, audio

Maybe I didn't search to good, but I wonder is there a way to play a sound on my Apple mobile device when the task is finished, for example call to `apply`?

Best Regards

Comment: You can send an e-mail with function `sendmailR::sendmail`, which is already quite awesome!

Comment: I don't see any R code here. Perhaps you should remove that tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is one of many possible answers, and happens to work very well for me.)

I use [Pushbullet](http://pushbullet.com) and [RPushbullet](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rpushbullet.html). After the initial setup (free account and free use), from any R instance (that has connectivity with the internet) I can run `pbNote('note', 'title', 'body of note')`, and it "instantly" comes up on my computer and mobile.

Because it is an R package/function, it can be easily scripted to meet whatever static/dynamic needs may arise. It can also send images (I'm told), files, addresses (think google maps), and lists.

Comment: BTW: this solution doesn't play a sound per se, but the [iPhone pushbullet client](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pushbullet/id810352052?mt=8) advertises "sound for in-app notifications."

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [twitteR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/index.html) package and tweet something when a long-lasting task is done. You can then setup a second twitter account to follow the account you tweet to from R and set an alarm for new tweets.

To be able to tweet from R, you have to go through all the authentication steps for Twitter, though.

Answer (score 0):

I use my own github package to send a text.  This is wrapping python code I didn't write and don't understand so I maintain it for myself but have not been able to address other people's problems:

https://github.com/trinker/gmailR

So the use may look something like:

```
gmail(to=cell2email(5555555555, "sprint"), password = "password")
```

Including this at the end of the script sends me a text when the long task is complete.  This really is taking advantage that cell numbers can be turned into email addresses if the cell carrier is known.